# Meteor can't subscribe to TAPi18n.Collection using TAPi18n.subscribe

Tags: mongodb, meteor, internationalization

I am using Meteor 1.5 and I am trying to subscribe to an `i18n` collection using these packages :

- TAP:i18n
- TAP:i18n-db

I ran `meteor create --full <appname>` to have the full scaffolded app.

Then I removed `insecure` and `autopublish` packages and added `aldeed:simple-schema`, `audit-argument-checks` and `mdg:validated-method` as recommended security mesures.

```
// imports/startup/server/fixtures.js

import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Links } from '../../api/links/links.js';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // if the Links collection is empty
  if (Links.find().count() === 0) {
    const data = [
      {
        title: 'Do the Tutorial',
        url: 'https://www.meteor.com/try',
        i18n: {
          'fr': {
            title: 'FR Do the Tutorial',
          },
        },
        createdAt: new Date(),
      },
      {
        ...
      },
    ];

    data.forEach(link => Links.insert(link));
  }
});
```

---

```
// imports/api/links/links.js

import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const Links = new TAPi18n.Collection('links');
```

---

```
// imports/api/links/server/publications.js

import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { TAPi18n } from 'meteor/tap:i18n';
import { Links } from '../links.js';

TAPi18n.publish('links.all', function () {
  return Links.i18nFind();
});
```

---

```
// client/main.js

import { TAPi18n } from 'meteor/tap:i18n';
import '/imports/startup/client';
import '/imports/startup/both';

Meteor.startup(function() {
    TAPi18n.setLanguage('en');
});
```

---

```
// imports/ui/components/info/info.js

import { Links } from '/imports/api/links/links.js';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { TAPi18n } from 'meteor/tap:i18n';
import './info.html';

Template.info.onCreated(function () {
  TAPi18n.subscribe('links.all');
});

Template.info.helpers({
  links() {
    return Links.find({});
  },
});

...
```

---

In Chrome console using Meteor Dev-Tool, I can see this :

[Chrome Meteor Dev-Tool screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9fjr.png)

Basically it says `unsubscribed from links.all (unrecognized subscription)`

In the server console, I can see this :

[Meteor Server Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2eWK.png)

I did some work to include `check` statement in `links.js` above but even when I check all fields, the app can't subscribe to the publication.

Any idea or help would be much appreciated.

The packages are not mandatory for me if there is a better example/repo somewhere I can actually look at.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you could not mix them up together. Use either `TAP:i18n-db` or `TAP:i18n`.

For examples have a look at the git repositories:

https://github.com/TAPevents/tap-i18n

https://github.com/TAPevents/tap-i18n-db

There are several examples you can have a look and decide to use only one of the packages.

Comment: Thanks for answering @PlanetaryDev both can be use since they are not for the same type of i18n. First is for string i18n inside Meteor while the other is for collection i18n inside Meteor.